# Selenium - Not being able to click links in search result

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am using Selenium plus python to search a keyword and then in the search result i am trying to clicking top 5 urls and getting data from p tag and then going back. So basically then i am storing the data from these 5 sites. But somehow after searching the keyword i am not being to click the urls and getting the data. i don't know whats wrong. This is the code i have written. Please Help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="E:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
print(driver.title)

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']").send_keys('selenium')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='FPdoLc tfB0Bf']//input[@name='btnK']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='g']/a[@href]")
links = []
for x in a:
    links.append(x.get_attribute('href'))
    link_data = []
for new_url in links:
    print('new url : ', new_url)
    driver.get(new_url)
    link_data.append(driver.page_source)

    b = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
    for data in b:
        print(data.text)

    driver.back()
    driver.close()
```

EDIT :
While navigating through links it is also including links from "People also ask " . i dont want to navigate through this box. How can i do it?
[image]

Comment: for your knowledge after some request, google will block or throw a captcha error

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong xpath for the links, should be:

```
"//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a[@href]"
```

If you look at the relevant part of the code, you'll see the `<a>` tag is not a child of `<div class="g">`, but of `<div class="yuRUbf">`

```html
<div class="g"><!--m-->
    <div class="tF2Cxc" data-hveid="CAkQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwjphfjOoazuAhUO1VkKHVSkA_oQFSgAMAp6BAgJEAA">
        <div class="yuRUbf"><a href="https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/selenium-benefits"
                               data-ved="2ahUKEwjphfjOoazuAhUO1VkKHVSkA_oQFjAKegQICRAC"
                               ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/selenium-benefits&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjphfjOoazuAhUO1VkKHVSkA_oQFjAKegQICRAC"><br>
            <h3 class="LC20lb DKV0Md"><span>7 Science-Based Health Benefits of Selenium - Healthline</span></h3>
            <div class="TbwUpd NJjxre"><cite class="iUh30 Zu0yb qLRx3b tjvcx">www.healthline.com<span
                    class="dyjrff qzEoUe"><span> › nutrition › selenium-benefits</span></span></cite></div>
        </a>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also change your search lines a bit too, but it doesn't change the overall effect:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']").send_keys('selenium', Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, also i have a doubt while navigating through links it is also including "People also ask" links . i don't want to include that. i have edited my question. how can i do it?

Comment: Try this as your xpath ```""//div[@id='center_col']//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a[@href]"``` There may be more efficient/safer ways to do it, I am no expert with xpath.

Comment: Does anyone know why is this specific string `'yuRUbf'` used? Does it mean something or is it just a bunch of random characters?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 16 or so links use.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
print(driver.title)

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']").send_keys('selenium')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='btnK']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='g']/div/div/a")
links = []
for x in a:
    links.append(x.get_attribute('href'))
    link_data = []
for new_url in links:
    print('new url : ', new_url)
    driver.get(new_url)
    link_data.append(driver.page_source)

    b = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
    for data in b:
        print(data.text)

    driver.back()
```

Comment: Also i have a doubt while navigating through links it is also including "People also ask" links . i don't want to include that. i have edited my question. how can i do it?